# Why 'Select' is called as DML statement ?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I see lot of debate of 'Select' being called as DML. Can some one explain me why its DML as its not manipulating any data on schema? As its puts locks on table should this be DML?

**In Wikipedia ** I can see

> "The purely read-only SELECT query statement is classed with the
>   'SQL-data' statements[2] and so is considered by the standard to be
>   outside of DML. The SELECT ... INTO form is considered to be DML
>   because it manipulates (i.e. modifies) data. In common practice
>   though, this distinction is not made and SELECT is widely considered
>   to be part of DML.[3]"

But in SELECT * FROM INSERT select will just perform selection nothing other than this!! Please someone help me in understanding this concept.

Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand in the Wikipedia excerpt ?

Comment: "will just perform selection nothing other than this" - you don't consider it creating a table and inserting data into that table something "other" than just selection?

Comment: @ X.L ANt Do you consider select as DML? If so please explain me what it data manipulates?

Comment: I don't, but it appears that some do (and SELECT INTO clearly is). I just find the excerpt clear.

Comment: In fact, it's also sometimes considered as the only command of DQL (Data Query Language).

Comment: I don't understand all the opinions and arguments here yet no-one has referred to the SQL Standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The distinction that people usually make is between DDL (data definition language, i.e. managing schema objects) and DML (data manipulation language, i.e. managing data within the schema created by DDL).  Clearly a SELECT is not DDL.

Comment: Just kidding as SELECT is not DDL why we should include this as DML ? should DML i need to understand as Data Managing Language??

Comment: Well, you can do grouping and aggregation and joins with a SELECT which manipulate data in a way, at least in how it is presented. The main difference for me is: DDL creates the schema. DML uses the schema.

Comment: I Be live I m doing healthy discussion here. If i m not wrong grouping and aggregation will not manipulate the data! I agree DML uses the sheme, and DDL creates, Uses (alter) schema. If langauge uses scehma can we group it as DMl ??

Comment: An important distinction in some (most?) implementations is also that DML (including SELECT) runs within a transaction, whereas DDL does not.

Comment: @Thilo - last time I checked, DDL participates in transactions also. Why would you think it doesn't?

Comment: Depends on the implementation. At least in Oracle it doesn't.

Comment: It's not what "people" think but what the SQL Standard defines.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: That standard seems to make the exact same distinction. I hope that downvote makes you happy.

Comment: @Colin'tHart If standards could not relate to what people think, they're useless. I'm just saying.

Answer (score 3):

Data Manipulation Language (DML) is a vocabulary used to query/retrieve and work with data. Don't go by the word Manipulation, such statement allows both data accessing and processing. As you have tagged question with SQL Server 2005 following link can be referred:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177591(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language It says  "The purely read-only SELECT query statement is classed with the 'SQL-data' statements[2] and so is considered by the standard to be outside of DML. The SELECT ... INTO form is considered to be DML because it manipulates (i.e. modifies) data. In common practice though, this distinction is not made and SELECT is widely considered to be part of DML.[3]"

Answer (score 3):

The *SQL Standard* considers SELECT part of "Data Manipulation".

An early version of the standard is available online at
http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

In section 13, "Data Manipulation" is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Why Select is DML statement in SQL?

[Click here for Link](http://royalarun.blogspot.in/2014/01/why-select-is-dml-statement-in-sql.html)

The SELECT ... INTO form is manipulates or modifies the data.

For eg

> SELECT Column1, Column2 INTO DestinationTable
>   FROM
>   SourceTable

Copy Coumn1,Column2 From SourceTable to DestinationTable.

So Select is dml statement

Comment: Is (SELECT Column1, Column2 INTO DestinationTable
FROM
SourceTable), this possible in Oracle.

Comment: I consider this answer not to be helpful; first of all, the question was about `select` in general, not specifically about `select into`; second, the description and content of the link are useless

Answer (score -2):

selct dept,max(salary)
from emp;
this query manipulate data then display so it is called as dml.
as we use aggregation functions and where clause with it so it shows manipulated data